# Adding Numbers in a Range with for() Loop

Tags: python

I'm having trouble filling out a question on an online python tutorial. It seems really simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out. This is the problem "**write a for loop that adds all the numbers 1 to 10 and returns the sum.**" And this is the code I have been trying:

```
def run():
    sum = 0
    for i in range(11):
        sum += i
        return sum
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're returning within the loop, after one iteration. You need to dedent the `return` statement so that it falls outside the loop:

```
def run():
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(11):
        sum_ += i
    return sum_
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot. Just started messing around with Python today so I'm still getting used to the syntax of everything. Thanks again!

Comment: don't use `sum` as a variable name, that way you can;t use the `sum()` `built-in.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone want to know how to add 0 + 1 count until 100. There is it!

```
  x = 0
    while x<100:
        x += 1
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the sum from within the for loop. Indent it outside. Keep it at the same level of indentation as for.

Comment: Nothing new =) Platinum Azure is very fast.

Comment: It's honestly just luck. For every answer I get first, I lose out on about ten.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure it is a fun game tough. :)

Answer (score 0):

## You need to dedent the return statement so that it falls outside the loop:

```
def addNumbers(num)
    sum=0
    for i in range(0,num+1)
        sum=sum+i
    return sum
```

Comment: Please edit you answer first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score -1):

def run(n):
total = 0
for item in range(n):
total = total + item
return total

print(run(11))

Comment: This is a copy/paste of the code in the 8 year old answer of Platinum Azure. Please don't copy (parts of) other people's answers and pass them off as your own. And when answering older question, please make sure that you provide either a different solution or at least a significantly better explanation than current answers.